# rpmbuild where do dependencies I didn't specify come from?

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

If you create an RPM using `rpmbuild -ba` and PHP scripts are included in the RPM, does it make this RPM automatically dependent on `/usr/bin/php` and `usr/bin/env`?

I am using `rpmbuild -ba` to package a Symfony project. Symfony has many PHP scripts with `#!/usr/bin/env php` as the first line in the script.

After the build if I execute `rpm -qp <rpm-package> --requires` it shows me dependencies on `/usr/bin/env`, `/usr/bin/php`, `/bin/sh` (listed twice? weird) and `/bin/bash`.

I see some scripts using `#!/bin/sh` where others use `#!/bin/bash`.

I would like to understand where these dependencies come from as they have not been specified in the .spec file as a "Requires" dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rpmbuild` automatically scans your files for dependencies (using `ldd` etc). You can find the documentation here: http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html

(**this is not recommended, but**) if you want to stop `rpmbuild` from doing this, you can put:

```
AutoReqProv: no
```

in your spec file.

Comment: While this does disable it, it is highly recommend you _don't_ unless you have a very good reason (TM).